# Джанго - Есть ли поле модели аналог ImageField, только без загрузки файла?

Tags: django

Всем доброго времени суток!

Вопрос: Есть ли поле модели аналог ImageField, только без загрузки файла?

Мне нужно реализовать выбор файла в админке из определенной папки с интерфейсом как у  ImageField (окно с перевью картинкой файла).

Я нашел вариант FilePathField (он не загружает файлы а дает выбрать из уже существующих, что и нужно), но он не подходит, так как выдает список без окна с возможностью просмотра перевью картинок.

Comment: Поля модели не выдают никакие списки и никакие окна. За внешний вид отвечают виджеты форм — и вы всегда можете нарисовать свой собственный виджет с нужными вам функциями, независимо от полей модели вообще

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, где можно найти информацию - как это сделать в Django?